# How To Join query DELETE AND UPDATE in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this :

[image: Table Employee]

and I want to write a query update after deleting a column, but I get an error, whether the query cannot be put together?

Query delete and update :

```
DELETE FROM employee 
WHERE id = '1' 
AND UPDATE employee 
    SET salary = '$731' 
    AND positions = 'Manager Production' 
    WHERE id = '2'
```

[image: Error Warning]

Comment: hum, I don't think you can do that

Comment: so i cant use delete and update query in one query?, so i must use a single query right?

Comment: yeah, you have to put them in separate queries Alif, like Ed's answer below

Comment: ok thanks for answer my question zip, i want use the query in my code...hehehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `line terminators` between your `dml` scripts.

```
delete from employee where id = '1';
update employee set salary = '$731' and positions = 'Manager Production' where id = '2'

delete from employee where id = '1'
go
update employee set salary = '$731' and positions = 'Manager Production' where id = '2'
```

Comment: thanks Ed for answer my question, you give the solution for my problem, cheer